# updated:IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matplotlib, image-processing

I have a questions about the following codes:
I want to return 2 values in this function, one is orig_image which is fine, the other one is the cx,cx is the x-coordinate of the center of the biggest contour which's area within certain range. The terminal saids "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)".(solved)
Next problem pops out: "IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0?"
May I know the reason and solution? Thankyou very much!

```
def findContours(image):
    orig_image = image.copy()
    image2 = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, image2 = cv2.threshold(image2, 127, 255, 1)
    image2 = cv2.Canny(image2,30,200)
    # Find contours 
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image2.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    max_area = 200000000000000
    min_area = 100
    areaList=[]
    cxList=[]
    if contours is not None:
        for c in contours:    

            area = cv2.contourArea(c)
            if min_area < area < max_area:
                areaList.append(area)
                approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.03*cv2.arcLength(c,True),False)

                cv2.drawContours(orig_image, [c], 0,(0,255,0), -1)
                # cv2.drawContours(orig_image, [c], 0,(225,0,0), -1)
                x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
                # cv2.rectangle(orig_image3,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)
                cx=x+int(w/2)
                cxList.append(cx)
                cy=y+int(h/2)
                cv2.circle(orig_image, (cx,cy), 5, (0,0,255), -1) 
        if areaList:    
            maxArea=max(areaList)
            index=np.where(areaList==maxArea)
            targetCx= cxList[index[0][0]]
            return targetCx #this is where the problem occur

    return orig_image #this is where the problem occur

def main():
       targetCx , original_image = findContours(original_image) #this is where 
       the problem occur
```

Terminal:

```
targetCx , original_image = findContours(original_image)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

If I change the last part to:

```
if areaList:    
        maxArea=max(areaList)
        index=np.where(areaList==maxArea)
        targetCx= cxList[index[0][0]]
        return targetCx
else:
        return None
return orig_image
```

Terminal Shows:

```
targetCx , original_image = findContours(original_image)
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

UPDATE

```
def findContours(image):
    orig_image = image
    image2 = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, image2 = cv2.threshold(image2, 127, 255, 1)
    image2 = cv2.Canny(image2,30,200)
    # Find contours 
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image2.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    max_area = 200000000000000
    min_area = 100
    areaList=[]
    cxList=[]
    targetCx =None
    if contours is not None:
        for c in contours:    

            area = cv2.contourArea(c)
            if min_area < area < max_area:
                areaList.append(area)
                approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.03*cv2.arcLength(c,True),False)

                cv2.drawContours(orig_image, [c], 0,(0,255,0), -1)
                # cv2.drawContours(orig_image, [c], 0,(225,0,0), -1)
                x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
                # cv2.rectangle(orig_image3,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)
                cx=x+int(w/2)
                cxList.append(cx)
                cy=y+int(h/2)
                cv2.circle(orig_image, (cx,cy), 5, (0,0,255), -1) 

    if areaList:
        maxArea=max(areaList)
        index=np.where(areaList==maxArea)
        targetCx = cxList[index[0][0]]

    return targetCx,orig_image
```

TERMINAL:

```
targetCx = cxList[index[0][0]]
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Comment: can you share which line the error is coming from?

Comment: Sure, I've already added , plz have a look thx!

Comment: The `where` probably didn't find any true values.  Look at `index` alone.

Comment: `maxArea=max(areaList)
        index=np.where(areaList==maxArea)` Im just getting the index of the maximum area in areaList, there should be a true value since its just from the same list.

Comment: The only way to test `shoulds` is to `debug` or print some of the intermediate values.  I don't trust `shoulds`, mine or anyone else's.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://opencv-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/doc/15.imageContours/imageContours.html#find-draw-contours), cv2.findContours() function returns 3 values(image, contours , hierarchy).

But you only try to unpack contours and hierarchy, and this makes error.
To fix this, change your code to `image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours()` .
or just do `_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours()` to not to use returned image.

**UPDATED**
The original question is changed while writing first answer.
The error message says, `I(Python) expected function call will returns exactly two values, but actually more than two are returned`.

Your `findContours` function's return value could be multiple form: None, targetCx, orig_image.
And at your function call side, you assume `findContours` function returns two return values exactly, tagetCx and original_image.

If `None` is returned, python cannot distribute it to your variables(targetCx, original_image) because `None` is not iterable.
I don't know what is in targetCx return value, maybe length of targetCx is greather than 2.

**Suggestion**
I think you want to get targetCx and original_image at the same time.
To achieve this, you should change your codes like this:

```
# ... code ...
targetCx = None  # Add this line
if contours is not None:
  # ... code ...
  # Remove all return statements inside function body
return targetCx, orig_image  # Change return orig_image to this
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thankyou but it doesn't seemsto be a problem as if I changed it to `_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours()`, Terminal shows `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)`

Comment: Thankyou I have tried but there is still a problem, `targetCx = cxList[index[0][0]]
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0`,however we are making progress , I have updated the question please kindly have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Technically your function only returns one item at a time. The function exits when one return is hit. So here would be a great case to have dual returns, and leave one as `None` at each section. I.e. -

```py
...
    if areaList:    
        maxArea=max(areaList)
        index=np.where(areaList==maxArea)
        targetCx= cxList[index[0][0]]
        return (None, targetCx) #x-coord is second

return (orig_image, None) #orig_image is first
```

and then do a check to determine which branch you go with. This way you can unpack two values (one will be `None`) and the return isn't an issue.

```py
original_image, targetCx = findContours(original_image)
if original_image is not None: 
    # do stuff with original_image
else:
    # do stuff with targetCx
```

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Thankyou I have tried but there is still a problem, `targetCx = cxList[index[0][0]] IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0`, I have searched about it but still don't know how to solve.

Comment: Do you ever set `cxList` equal to anything other than `cxList=[]`? Because if not, that is a critical problem, and explains the problems you have. If you never set it equal to anything else, or add anything to it via `cxList.append(<thing>)`, there will never be anything at `cxList[index[0][0]]`.

Also of note is the option that `index` doesn't have anything at `[0]` or that `index[0]` doesn't have anything at `[0]`.

Comment: yes I used `if areaList:` first to ensure there is something inside cxList, as cxList is just the x coordinates of  the contours i found and the length of cxList should be the same as areaList, so if areaList is not None then cxList shoudn't be None either. I want to find the biggest controur(max area) and get its x coordinate to be targetCx.

Comment: Ok I missed the append line in the nested if. There is potentially another couple problems.

If `contours` is nothing, it's all over. This is compounded by the fact that even if `contours` is None, you set `areaList=[]` so it's no longer `None`. 

Have you tried printing out each of these items before they are used? A la:  

```python
    if areaList:
        print(areaList)
        maxArea=max(areaList)
        print(maxArea)
        index=np.where(areaList==maxArea)
        print(index[0][0])
        targetCx= cxList[index[0][0]]
    return targetCx,orig_image
```